# Roots of a specific complex polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find if the complex polynomial (defined below) has any special properties that would help me find its roots:

$p(z) = a + \overline{a}z^6 + bz + \overline{b}z^5 + cz^2 + \overline{c}z^4 + d z^3$

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If $z$ is a root, so is $\frac1{\overline z}$...?

Comment: That seems to be true, but how did you get there?

Comment: $p(z)=0 \implies \overline{p(z)}=0 \implies \overline z^6 p(1/\overline z)=0 \implies p(1/\overline z)=0$ as $a\neq0\implies z=0$ is not a root.. You may want to read up on self-conjugate and self-inverse polynomials, as you can transform this to a depressed/ soluble form using a variant of Möbius transformation.